# How is a piece determined by PL/SQL utl_http.html_pieces

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for some help understanding how the request_pieces function works. What defines what a piece is or does it take a select amount characters to build a piece e.g. The first 2000 characters will be a peice.

I additionally have an error from the following PL/SQL block -  PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

```
DECLARE 
  x utl_http.html_pieces;
BEGIN
  x := utl_http.request_pieces('www.testwebsite.co.uk', 100);
  dbms_output.put_line(x.count || ' pieces were retrieved.');
  dbms_output.put_line('with total length ');
  IF x.count < 1 
  THEN dbms_output.put_line('0');
  ELSE dbms_output.put_line
  ((2000 * (x.count - 1)) + length(x(x.count)));
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REQUEST_PIECES iterates over READ_TEXT or READ_RAW until it gets an END_OF_BODY. If the content returned by READ_TEXT is over 2000 (bytes ?) then it will fail inside UTL_HTTP. If that's the problem, I'd go with calling READ_TEXT specifically in your own loop with a VARCHAR2(32000) variable and see if that works.

If the underlying Oracle logic is trying to get it in 2000 sized chunks there may be oddities in character set conversions / multibyte characters which might give the occasional miscount (though it should give a partial_multibyte_char exception). Possibly setting a content-type HTTP header would help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about [UTL_HTTP.REQUEST_PIECES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm#i998146). Please read the documentation for more details.

<s>Yes, each piece is 2000 characters. For example, if the requested data is 5000 characters long, the first two pieces will be 2000 characters, and the third piece will be 1000.</s>

I take that back. The documentation says:

> Each entry of the PL/SQL table (the "pieces") returned by this function may not be filled to their fullest capacity. The function may start filling the data in the next piece before the previous "piece" is totally full.

They aren't really clear on how that happens. So each piece is between 1-2000 characters?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have a block of code which returns the Numeric or Value Error: String Buffer too small. The web page I am using is 11,286 character long with spaces. Am I right in assuming the function isn't strictly the problem here.

Comment: I'm not sure. The documentation isn't really very clear for this function, and I don't have an easy way to test it at the moment.